# Uploading multiple images on twitter using Ruby on Rails Twitter Gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter, twitter-gem

What should be the format for the parameter: `media` , in the call below, for updating with multiple images.

```
def twitter_status_update_with_media (twitter_client, text, media, opts)
    twitter_client.update_with_media(self.text, media, opts)
end
```

For a single image, `File.new(filepath)` works fine..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To attach multiple images to a tweet, you first need to upload the images using the `upload` method:

```
media_ids = %w(image1.png image2.png image3.png image4.png).map do |filename|
  Thread.new do
    twitter_client.upload(File.new(filename))
  end
end.map(&:value)
```

This will return media IDs, which you can pass into the `media_ids` parameter (as a comma-separated string) of the `update` method.

```
twitter_client.update("Tweet text", :media_ids => media_ids.join(','))
```

Comment: how would I apply this code to change the user profile image/avatar?

Comment: If media_ids array is empty, the line above will return an error: `Twitter::Error::BadRequest: media_ids parameter is invalid.`. Be careful.